# How to create CSV file in Downloads directory Android 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file, storage

I've been struggling to create a CSV file from my app. Here's my code:

```
private void createFile() throws IOException {
        Log.i("test", "creating file");
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "/test.csv");
        if (!file.createNewFile()) {
            Log.i("test", "file doesn't exist");
            try {
                Log.i("test", "gonna create the new file");
                Log.i("test", "done :)");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (!file.exists()) {
            Log.i("test", "Oh no");
            return;
        }
}
```

The Logcat prints:

`creating file`
`file doesn't exist`
`gonna create the new file`
`Oh no`

I don't know why `file.createNewFile()` returns false yet when I check if it exists, it also returns false.

I have my permissions declared in my Manifest and enabled storage permissions from settings as well.

I also have a function that checks if I have storage perms and it says that I do.

Comment: `createNewFile()` returns `false` when the file already exists, and `true` when it didn't. Try removing the slash from `/test.csv`

Comment: @HengYe that doesn't work :(

Comment: Try looking at [How to Create a csv file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15403113/16653700).